# Building the correct equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the question

> In a class, there are $40$ people who at least know french or german.
>   The value of people who know german is $2$ times of people who know
>   french and $4$ times of who know both language.
>
> - How many people who know german are there?

My Approach

I drew up the venn diagram.
[image]

$$r(1) = \text {who knows german}$$
$$r(2) = \text {who know french}$$
$$r(3) = \text {who know both}$$

What equation should we use to find how many people who know german there are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r(1)+r(2)+r(3)=40$$

---

$$r(1)+ r(3)=2 \times [r(2)+r(3)]$$

$$r(1)- r(3)=2 \times r(2)$$

---

$$r(1)+ r(3) = 4 \times r(3)$$

$$r(1) = 3 \times r(3)$$

You need to find $r(1) + r(3)$ so just play with the equations and find values of all values, $r(1)$, $r(2)$ and $r(3)$.

Comment: This gives non-integer answers though...$r_1=\dfrac{160}{7}$

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Thanks! Corrected. I forgot to account for **only** German/French speaking.

Comment: @MaadhavGupta Nice to see you again! you show your great answers again, don't you?

Comment: @Korrigi Hah, likewise!

Comment: Also, I was going to ask a question to you. Assume that the total wasn't given, can we use this method?

Comment: Could you be more clear at $r(1)+ r(3)=2 \times [r(2)+r(3)]$ part?

Comment: @Korrigi You can use this in any question which is not too complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68234/discussion-between-maadhav-gupta-and-korrigi).

Comment: @MaadhavGupta Great;)